# In bash or shell, how does one input a line of text as a file without making a temp file?

Tags: bash, input

### Problem 1:

I'm using a self-made command, that for reasons, cannot be changed. The command requires a filename that it will read from like so: `read-cmd "testtext.txt"` I know it's possible to use files as a stream of input for some commands using input redirection, e.g. `some-cmd < "text.txt"`, but I'm wondering if the opposite is true, whether I can use a line of text and make bash believe it's a file, so that I'd be able to do `read-cmd "contents of what should be in a text file"`

the only thing I've been able to do is

```
Example 1:
echo "contents of what should be in a text file" > tmptextfile
read-cmd "tmptextfile"
rm tmptextfile
```

I would however, really rather not do this, and rather just stream that line in as if it were a file. Is there any possible way to do this, or would it rely entirely on how `read-cmd` works?

### Problem 2:

A very similar issue, however, instead of the file being an input to a command, it is the input to an *option* of a command. So, `read-cmd2 -d "testtext.txt" ...`

```
Example 2:
echo "contents of what should be in options text file" > tmpoptfile
read-cmd2 -d tmpoptfile ...
rm tmpoptfile
```

Comment: Interesting! What if you just pipe and make your command read from stdin?

Comment: `echo 'contents blah blah'| xargs read-cmd`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> whether I can use a line of text and make bash believe it's a file,

Yes you can use [**process substitution**](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) for this:

```
read-cmd <(echo "contents of what should be in a text file")
```

**Process substitution is a form of redirection where the input or output of a process (some sequence of commands) appear as a temporary file.**

Comment: Test with some built-in utility rather than `read-cmd` which we don't know what it is doing. For example: `grep -Eo '\b[tw][^ ]*' <(echo "contents of what should be in a text file")`

Comment: When using this to pass the text to a c++ executable i made, that only takes files as args, it produces a bad alloc error ?

Comment: Apologies, actually this works for Example 1. This still does not work for example 2, however.

Comment: Realised why it didn't work and why it may not work for OP, process substition does not allow for random file access.

Comment: @echolocation: `process substitution` makes command output available to some program as a file but it won't work with your new command: `read-cmd2 -d tmpoptfile`